# Geoserver api: how to determine a layers respective workspace?

Tags: geoserver, layers, boundless-suite, api, workspace

I am using the geoserver api to find information about layers that are available. I am using:

```
http://localhost/geoserver/rest/layers.json
```

to get a dynamic list of all layers. 
If I then select a layer with:

```
http://localhost/geoserver/rest/layers/<myLayer>.json
```

I get information about the layer.

How can I determine the layers respective workspace?

Comment: http://localhost/geoserver/rest/workspaces

Answer (score 3):

From the layer, follow the link to the associated feature type

```
"resource":{"@class":"featureType","name":"ne_10m_populated_places","href":"http:\/\/scale.dev.opengeo.org\/geoserver\/rest\/workspaces\/naturalearth\/datastores\/ne\/featuretypes\/ne_10m_populated_places.json"}
```

then to the data store for that feature type

```
"store":{"@class":"dataStore","name":"ne","href":"http:\/\/scale.dev.opengeo.org\/geoserver\/rest\/workspaces\/naturalearth\/datastores\/ne.json"}
```

and then from there there's a link to the workspace

```
"workspace":{"name":"naturalearth","href":"http:\/\/scale.dev.opengeo.org\/geoserver\/rest\/workspaces\/naturalearth.json"}
```

You could also look at the path to the feature type which will include the workspace, although that's not quite as "correct" a method, it does save you from having to load all those extra resources.